# I made an animation of 26 frames, how do I turn it into a 30 frame animation to export it into unreal engine?

Tags: animation, export

I have an animation and I need to make it longer so it becomes compatible with unreal engine 5.

Comment: what do you use? blender?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Time Stretching function to remap your time faster or slower
[image]